# MySQL, PHP Prepared Statements Matching a String

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I use prepared statements rather frequently to insert data, but I'm trying to select data and having an issue I can't seem to wrap my head around.

This code does not work at all.  No error, just no results:

```
$student_name = "Student, Sample";
$student_number = "";

$SQLStmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT student_number FROM table WHERE `name` = ?" );
$SQLStmt->bind_param( "s", $student_name );
$SQLStmt->bind_result( $student_number );
$SQLStmt->execute();
$SQLStmt->store_result();
echo $student_number;
```

This code works just fine:

```
$student_name = "Student, Sample";
$student_number = "";

$SQLStatement = "SELECT student_number FROM table WHERE `name` = '".$student_name."'";
$result = $db->query($SQLStatement);
$myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();         
echo $myrow['student_number'];
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: To get errors out of PHP _even in a LIVE environment_ add these 4 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Actually 3 of these lines should be permanent, and only display_errors should be switched on and off depends on the server role

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yea, I know, but having worked on code from dubious area's of the world, that always started by turning all error processing off because the code was so terriible. I now assume, rightly or wrongly, that its likely error processing is turned off so the dev's can move on to the billing phase before the client realises they bought a pig in a poke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not fetch rows from the resultset

```
$SQLStmt->store_result();
```

Try instead

```
$student_name = "Student, Sample";
$student_number = "";

$SQLStmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT student_number FROM table WHERE `name` = ?" );
$SQLStmt->bind_param( "s", $student_name );
$SQLStmt->bind_result( $student_number );
$SQLStmt->execute();
$results = SQLStmt->get_results();
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['student_number'];
```

Comment: Thank you!  Of course...the Fetch Statement!   I added $SQLStmt->fetch(); and now it works